# PHP-Twitch don't get vars

Tags: php, twitch

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams");
    $elements = json_decode($json,true);
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $channel = get_object_vars($element);
        print_r(array_keys($channel));
    }
?>
```

The errors:

> get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given in /home/xzer123/public_html/tw1.php on line 10
>
> array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/xzer123/public_html/tw1.php on line 11

what happened wrong?

Comment: It tells you, that `$element` is an array, not an object. And it is true.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter to [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) specifies that you want the result as an array.

Change it to `false` or you can just remove it, because it defaults to `false`.

[`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) is expecting an object and not an array to be passed to it.

Comment: thanks i get an array, but what does it mean? how i can use it? in code

Comment: Try calling `print_r($elements)` and you'll get an idea as to what the Twitch API is returning to you.

Comment: Array ( [0] => self [1] => next [2] => featured [3] => summary [4] => followed ) but i have no idea how to use it -- echo $element->self; ?

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do. I suggest you read some PHP tutorials though.

Comment: I need to take the values ​​of the array, which parses from api, php is not good enough learn..

Answer (score 0):

To extract the contents as **an array** and not as an object you can use this code , first `json_decode` the results with 2 nd parameter is set to `true` then you will get a multidimensional array.

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams");
    $elements = json_decode($json,true);

    foreach ($elements['streams'] as $element) {

        print_r(array_keys($element));
    }
?>
```